# How can I make the deformation to a canvas mesh in dynamic paint permanent?

Tags: dynamic-paint

With dynamic paint on a canvas, in Vertex format, I used the "Waves" surface type option in the "Dynamic Paint Advanced" option . The canvas becomes deformed as expected when I press play in the timeline. Now I want to make the deformation in a certain frame permanent so when I enter edit mode, the deformation is still there. Is it possible to make it permanent?

(I found that if I export the canvas to fbx on a certain frame and re-import it, the deformation is there, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic paint deforms the mesh through the modifier system. To leave a mesh permanently deformed based on any modifiers operation you apply the modifier.

[image]